# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '$16.10' (I fixed the question I just need some help to lay off my question ban)

Tags: python, class, valueerror

The code below is my current code

```
class Money(object):
    def __init__(self, dollars=0, cents=0):
        self.dollars = dollars + cents//100
        self.cents = cents %100
    def __radd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Money):
            other = other.cents + other.dollars * 100
        elif isinstance(other, int):
            other = other * 100
        elif isinstance(other, float):
            other = int(other * 100)
        money = int(other) + float(self.cents + self.dollars * 100)
        self.dollars = money // 100
        self.cents = money % 100
        return "$%d.%2d" %(self.dollars,self.cents)
def money_text_2():
    m1 = Money(3, 50)
    m2 = Money(2, 60)
    print(m1 == m2)
    print(m1 + m2)
    print(10 + m1 + m2)
money_text()
```

But it keeps getting this error:

```
money = int(other) + float(self.cents + self.dollars * 100)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '$16.10'
```

I spent the past 30 minutes trying to find a solution with no results

Can someone point it out for me?

Comment: Beside the point, but why are you updating instance attributes in `__radd__()`, which should be a pure method? Did you mistake it for [`__iadd__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__)?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, but I do get other errors depending on what I try. Firstly, `Money2` is not defined. After changing it to `Money`, I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Money' and 'Money'` at `print(m1 + m2)`. I'm pretty sure the error you're getting is thrown one line after that. Please provide a [mre] including the full traceback. You can [edit] the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix the ValueError and some other bugs, add more test cases.

- ValueError:After you add 10 and m1,you return a string like `$13.50`,which can't pass any if statement in your `__radd__` method. So you got a ValueError in `print(10 + m1 + m2)`, which you attempt to add a string to a Money class. I fix it to return a Money instance and `__repr__` to display the format you want.
- The Money class only got `__radd__` method, which can't pass test case like `m1 + 10 + m2`.I add `__ladd__` method to handle it.
- Also,the Money class don't have `__add__` method. I add it to handle test case like `m1 + m2`
- `Money2` not defined error.

code:

```
class Money(object):
    def __init__(self, dollars=0, cents=0):
        self.dollars = dollars + cents//100
        self.cents = cents %100

    def add_func(self,other):
        if isinstance(other, Money):
            other = other.cents + other.dollars * 100
        elif isinstance(other, int):
            other = other * 100
        elif isinstance(other, float):
            other = int(other * 100)
        money = int(other) + float(self.cents + self.dollars * 100)
        return Money(money // 100,money % 100)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.add_func(other)

    def __ladd__(self,other):
        return self.add_func(other)

    def __radd__(self,other):
        return self.add_func(other)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "$%d.%2d" %(self.dollars,self.cents)

def money_text():
    m1 = Money(3, 50)
    m2 = Money(2, 60)
    print(m1 == m2)
    print(m1 + m2)
    print(m1 + 10 + m2)
    print(10 + m1 + m2)

    m3 = Money(1, 0)
    m4 = Money(0, 99)
    print(m3 + m4)
    print(1.5 + m3 + m4)

money_text()
```

result:

```
False
$6.10
$16.10
$16.10
$1.99
$3.49
```